# Projection of QP problem solved with Gradient Descent

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, constraint, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, heuristics

Lets say we have a QP problem as shown below

$$\min {\bf x}^T {\bf R}{\bf x}+{\bf c}^T{\bf x}$$

subject to

$${\bf A_{eq}x}={\bf e}_{eq}$$

$${\bf Ax}\le {\bf e}$$

$${\bf x}\in \lbrace 0,1\rbrace$$

${\bf x}$ is of very large size, e.g., 40000.

I can solve it with gradient descent method. Then how can I do the projection heuristically based on the equality and inequality constraints?

After solving the QP with gradient descent we get some continuous values for ${\bf x}$

How can I map them back to binary heuristically based on the constraints?

Note: Both ${\bf A}_{eq}$ and ${\bf A}$ are binary matrices

Comment: Your constraints do not seem to involve the decision variables $x$.

Comment: @prubin sorry for the mistake. Corrected it now.

Comment: Are you willing to solve a MILP to get back to binary values?

Comment: @prubin yes. After solving may be with gradient descent, I get continuous values for the optimization variable. How can I map them back to binary values depending on the matrix ${\bf A}_{eq}$, ${\bf A}$. In my case both ${\bf A}_{eq}$ and  ${\bf A}$ are binary matrix.

Comment: Is your objective function convex (is ${\bf R}$ positive semidefinite)? If so, you might be better off solving the problem directly with a MIQP solver rather than doing gradient descent followed by a MILP model to get to a feasible (but likely not optimal) solution.

Comment: Solving an MIP with gradient descent! Even with neglecting the integrality constraints (which are causing the main difficulty), solving this problem by projected gradient descent is not practical as the projection on  a general polyhedral does not have a closed form. This is an MIQP problem.